# Can subdomains point to different server platforms?

Tags: php, asp.net, subdomain, web-hosting

I have a website which is developed using asp.net. I have created a new module which is in PHP. Without disturbing the main site I need to host this site.

Is it possible to host like that or not?

Example:

```
www.vidhyaprakash.com - aspx
account.vidhyaprakash.com - php
```

Comment: how should we know? You haven't mentioned anything about your server environment, dns setups, etc... "probably" is about all you'll get from us.

Comment: Should be possible in theory with reverse proxying, but all my experience with that has been with Apache.

Comment: no bro i already have website. i asking you whether it is possible. if possible how. now i am in danger please help me.

Comment: as long as you use different ports I can't think of a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sub domains like domains are just IP addresses with names (or rather names that point to IP addresses).  The DNS can be configured to point to any IP address.

You may need to ask your provider to do this for you.  They set up a CNAME.
I personally have my web hosting on my main domain, but I have a subdomain which points to a gaming server.

EDIT:

A trick for example, is to have a domain or sub domain which points to a DYN server, which in turn points to a server with a dynamic IP.

Comment: then it is possible right? Flosculus

Comment: i.e. yes, its what they are for. edit: they allow you to create addon domains while using the subscription (in most cases) of the main one.

Comment: whether u know any provider who can help me?

Comment: host/provider, same thing, i assumed you already had one.

Comment: but that one is done by some other company with some provider. i planned for vps and point to that sub domain

Comment: it is the provider of the domain `vidhyaprakash.com` that will need to set this up for you.  If you are looking for VPS hosting, try gbservers.co.uk, if you are hosting in the UK.  I can't help you more than that, and we are trailing out of the scope of your original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55720/discussion-between-vidhya-prakash-and-flosculus).